# WPF TextBox copy is truncating

Tags: wpf, textbox, clipboard

Is there a property that limits the size of the clipboard within a WPF TextBox?  I am dumping debug/log information to a bound text box.  When I copy all the contents and try to paste to a text editor, I'm only getting a small portion of the data (<4 KB).

Comment: Perhaps an alternative would be to dump the debug/log information to a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090451/limit-on-text-data-size-in-clipboard

Comment: Does this text editor let you paste large amounts of text from any other source? Worth checking just in case. Have you looked at Clipboard.GetText().Length right after you copy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you limiting the **TextBox.MaxLength** or something? I haven't faced such an issue in any of my projects yet. I have used multiline textboxes and used to copy huge amounts of text content from those textboxes.

It actually depends upon the total virtual memory. Normally applications call GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_DDESHARE) to allocate the memory for data to be stored on the clipboard and make it available to other applications. For 32-bit applications GlobalAlloc can allocate blocks up to 2 GB in size or up to the amount of virtual memory the PC has, whichever is less. The Windows clipboard does not impose any other size limits.

Read more on **GlobalAlloc** at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574(v=vs.85).aspx